# Can we declare both implicit and explicit properties for columns in the "grid" shorthand?

Tags: html, css, layout, css-grid

I have searched a lot of places but haven't found the answer.

The doubt is how can we declare both the implicit and the explicit properties in the grid shorthand. Like this:

```
            grid: 30% min-content 5% auto-flow 20vh / repeat(6, 1fr);
```

I want to convert the following properties in the shorthand:

```
        .container{
        grid-template-rows: 30% min-content 5%;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
        grid-auto-flow: row;
        grid-auto-rows: 
        20vh;
    }
```

So, can we declare both types of values at once?

And if you are going to say, use the repeat() function in it, then I can't because the container is scrollable so auto-fit or auto-fill breaks the layout and without them how could I repeat it for any number of times required?

Comment: No. By definition implicit meams undefined.

Comment: @Paulie_D implicit doesn't mean undefined. In CSS grid we can define the implicit grid configuration and "grid" can do it --> *The grid property is a shorthand that sets all of the explicit grid properties (grid-template-rows, grid-template-columns, and grid-template-areas), and all the implicit grid properties (grid-auto-rows, grid-auto-columns, and grid-auto-flow), in a single declaration.* https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#grid-shorthand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this. You can either define the explicit or the implicit configuration for each axis. So either you define "implicit row"/"explicit column" or "explicit row"/"implicit column" but you cannot have "explicit row"/"implicit row"/"explicit column"

You can check [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#grid-shorthand) for the full syntax:

> Sets up auto-flow, by setting the tracks **in one axis explicitly** (setting either `grid-template-rows` or `grid-template-columns` as specified, and setting the other to none), and specifying how **to auto-repeat the tracks in the other axis** (setting either `grid-auto-rows` or `grid-auto-columns` as specified, and setting the other to auto). grid-auto-flow is also set to either row or column accordingly, with dense if it’s specified.

As you can read, you cannot have `grid-template-rows` and `grid-auto-rows` together

The best you can do is:

```css
.container {
  grid: auto-flow 20vh / repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 30% min-content 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

In that same specification you can also read:

> Note that you can only specify the explicit or the implicit grid properties in a single grid declaration.

The above apply to each axis.